# Identifying background window without activation

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to send keystrokes to the window in the background.
This window does not have a name. I cannot find a way to identify the window without activating it. Is it possible ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the solution, with the tips from the people in these forums.

By using "AutoIt3 Window Spy" program (which comes with ahk script) I've identified that one part of the class name of the window doesn't change.

By using SetTitleMatchMode in RegEx mode (so that script would need only part of the ahk_class to identify the window) I was able to reach the result I needed - to send keystrokes to the window without activating it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [ControlSend](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm) command. You can use `WinTitle` and/or `WinText` to identify window. So, if the window has no `WinTitle` use `WinText`. `WinText` is a part of a text of the element of the target window. If you want to use `WinText` of the hidden element of the window you need to use [DetectHiddenText](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/DetectHiddenText.htm) command, like this: `DetectHiddenText, On`

**Edited 1** (suggested by **Joe DF**):
You can get `WinTitle` and `WinText` with utility "AutoIt3 Window Spy" which is installed with AutoHotkey (look in start menu folder.). Also similar utility (I use that one) is built-in [SciTE4AutoHotkey](http://fincs.ahk4.net/scite4ahk/).

**Edited 2** (in response to **Maushas Laumaris** comment):
As far as I understand from [here](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm) you can also use `ahk_class` instead of `WinTitle`. I marked your window `ahk_class` on the picture below:
[image]

Comment: also, tell him about the window spy! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tips :)

Sadly, I was not able to use wintext to help me - as I understand, wintext doesn't find anything either. Here is a link to the information about the window I'm interested in, when I use AutoIt3 Window Spy (neat program ;) ) on it : http://postimg.org/image/q2apwxx9b/

Comment: @Maushas Laumaris Look at my answer at section **Edited 2**. I think it will help you.

Comment: I actually tried to use the class too... The same problem still remains - even though the window has a way to be identified, I cannot extract that identification without activating the window.

The class of the window is always different, so that means I cannot hardcode the class name and use it in the script. That is the reason why I need to get the class (or ID, or anything else with which I can identify the window) from the window after it loads.
Maybe it is possible to not match class completely, but to match only part of the class ? (HwndWrapper part seems to be the same every time)?

Comment: @Maushas Laumaris I don't know if class can be match partially. Try to use `Process Name/Path` http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#ahk_exe .

Comment: Figured it out!
Class can be matched partially by using SetTitleMatchMode in RegEx mode. Woohoooo!
Thx for all the effort people! :)

Comment: @Maushas Laumaris You are welcome :) Please post the solution as answer and accept it so others can use your solution.

Comment: vasili111, you mean "please accept my solution so i get more stackoverlow points"

Comment: @mikew Please read our discussion more carefully. My answer did not gave solution, so my answer does not have solution and cannot be accepted. **Maushas Laumaris** found solution and I asked him to share with community his solution and accept it.